# Unable to extract data from QR code in android

Tags: java, android, html

After scan QR code, app will get Event title, start date, end date and location.

(**html code:** `encodeURIComponent(txt1 + "\n" + txt2 + "\n" + txt3 + "\n" + txt4)`)

And how to put those value into this code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents()==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You Cancelled the Scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", ?);
            intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
            intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
            intent.putExtra("endTime", ?);
            intent.putExtra("title", ?);
            intent.putExtra("eventLocation", ?);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're having trouble with.

Comment: After scan QR code, we got "Event title <br> start date <br> end date <br> location", and we hope event title can put into `intent.putExtra("title", **there**);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split()` to divide the string into substring. This will give you an array of strings that you can pass to the intent.

```
        String result = "Event title <br> start date <br> end date <br> location"
        String[] info = result.split("<br>");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", info[1].trim());
        intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        intent.putExtra("endTime", info[2].trim());
        intent.putExtra("title", info[0].trim());
        intent.putExtra("eventLocation", info[3].trim());
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It didn't work out. User can make a QR code at website (they can fill in event title, start date, end date and location). After scan the QR code, those information will read into calendar. But we don't know how to get those contents into 'intent.putExtra'.